# Converting INT to DATE then using GETDATE on conversion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, int, getdate

I am trying to convert the results from an INT column to DATE so the GETDATE function will be compatible with this column. The date is currently in the format yyyymmdd

This is what I have so far based on what I could find but I am sure it is completely wrong

```
...AND (dbo.V_HEAD.LF_DATE CONVERT(DATE,(CONVERT(INT, LF_DATE)) >= GETDATE-28)

AND (dbo.V_HEAD.LF_DATE CONVERT(DATE,(CONVERT(INT, LF_DATE)) <= GETDATE)...
```

I want the results qualified on LF_DATE for the last 28 days too

The rest of the script runs correctly.
Where am I going wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: Your sql is not valid. What is the type of `LF_DATE`?

Comment: rather than `GETDATE`, you could try using `DATEADD` function to get your date range.

Comment: LF_DATE is an INTEGER

Comment: I don't understand this syntax: AND (dbo.V_HEAD.LF_DATE CONVERT(DATE,(CONVERT(INT, LF_DATE)) >= GETDATE-28) .

Comment: Sorry there are several selections in the statement. I have just cut out the section of the script I was having trouble with. I want a stored procedure that will return the results for the last 28 days no matter when I run it. Which is why I wanted to use GETDATE

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Following your comments, I've created some sample data to test my answer:
Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    Id int,
    ActualDate Date,
    LF_Date int
)

INSERT INTO @T (Id, ActualDate) VALUES
(10, DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())),
(9, DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())),
(8, DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())),
(7, DATEADD(DAY, -20, GETDATE())),
(6, DATEADD(DAY, -25, GETDATE())),
(5, DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())),
(4, DATEADD(DAY, -35, GETDATE())),
(3, DATEADD(DAY, -40, GETDATE())),
(2, DATEADD(DAY, -45, GETDATE())),
(1, DATEADD(DAY, -50, GETDATE()))

UPDATE @T 
SET LF_Date = YEAR(ActualDate) * 10000 + MONTH(ActualDate) * 100 + DAY(ActualDate)
```

Test sample data:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Id          ActualDate  LF_Date
----------- ----------  -----------
10          2016-08-09  20160809
9           2016-08-04  20160804
8           2016-07-30  20160730
7           2016-07-25  20160725
6           2016-07-20  20160720
5           2016-07-15  20160715
4           2016-07-10  20160710
3           2016-07-05  20160705
2           2016-06-30  20160630
1           2016-06-25  20160625
```

As you can see, the sample table's `LF_Date` column is an `int` that keeps the date as `yyyyMMdd`, just like in the question.

The query:

```
DECLARE @DateAsInt int,
        @Date date = GETDATE();

SELECT @DateAsInt = YEAR(@Date) * 10000 + MONTH(@Date) * 100 + DAY(@Date);

SELECT *
FROM @T 
WHERE LF_DATE >= @DateAsInt - 28
AND LF_DATE <= @DateAsInt
```

Results:

```
Id          ActualDate  LF_Date
----------- ----------  -----------
10          2016-08-09  20160809
9           2016-08-04  20160804
```

### Conclusion:

as far as the sample data goes, the answer is fine. You need to test your data to see what's stopping you from getting the results from the previous month, but I seriously doubt that it's my suggestion.

**First version**
Assuming your Sql server version is 2012 or higher, you can use some math and the [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) built in function:

```
DECLARE @IntDate int = 20160322

SELECT  DATEFROMPARTS (
            (@IntDate - (@IntDate % 10000)) / 10000,
            (@IntDate % 1000) / 100,
            @IntDate % 100
        ) As [Date]
```

Results:

```
Date
2016-03-22
```

However, It will be simpler and probably have a better performance to convert the `date` to `int`:

```
DECLARE @Date date = '2016-03-22'

SELECT  YEAR(@Date) * 10000 + 
        MONTH(@Date) * 100 + 
        DAY(@Date) As [Int]
```

Results:

```
Int
20160322
```

To put that in context of your question - calculate the int value of the current date before your query:

```
DECLARE @DateAsInt int,
        @Date date = GETDATE();
    
SELECT @DateAsInt = YEAR(@Date) * 10000 + MONTH(@Date) * 100 + DAY(@Date);
```

And then, in your where clause you simply write this:

```
...
AND LF_DATE >= @DateAsInt - 28
AND LF_DATE <= @DateAsInt
...
```

In any case, you will be better off if you could change your table structure and replace that int column with a date column.
Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Thanks it now works in part, the problem is the results do not extend to the previous month when I use @DateAsInt - 28

Comment: Thanks it now works in part, the problem is the results do not extend to the previous month. I ran @DateAsInt - 28 today,  it only returns results up to the start of the month. I.e 01 Aug 2016

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help

```
Select DateAdd(DD,-28,cast(cast(20160809 as varchar(8)) as date))
```

Returns 2016-07-12

**However**, since your data is an int, I think it would be more efficient to convert the desired date range into an int rather than performing row level calculations

```
Declare @DateR1 int = Format(DateAdd(DD,-28,GetDate()),'yyyyMMdd')
Declare @DateR2 int = Format(GetDate(),'yyyyMMdd')

Select DateR1=@DateR1,DateR2=@DateR2
```

Returns

```
DateR1      DateR2
20160712    20160809
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zohar Peled, I think I have cracked it! It is subtracting 28 as an int and not days.
The problem is 20160809 - 28 = 20160781 which is no good

The desired results would be

SELECT *
FROM @T 
WHERE LF_DATE >= @DateAsInt - 28 (DAYS)
AND LF_DATE <= @DateAsInt

Id          ActualDate  LF_Date

---

10          2016-08-09  20160809
9           2016-08-04  20160804
8           2016-07-30  20160730
7           2016-07-25  20160725
6           2016-07-20  20160720
5           2016-07-15  20160715

As 20160809 - 28 DAYS would include dates from 20160712

The way around this was to subtract 97 instead of 28.

This this is not very clean, there must be a better way...

Comment: Yes, there is a better way - don't use the wrong data type. Keep dates in a date column.

Comment: I have inherited this database. I had nothing to do with the structure